# Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a simple CART style mixed effects model using the REEMtree. I don't understand why it keeps throwing the error:

> "Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 1 (the number of
>   columns), not 120"

Here is the sample data:

```
structure(list(avg_ipt = c(14, 8.666666667, 30, 3.857142857, 
2.153846154, 2.363636364, 2.071428571, 2.25, 1.636363636, 14, 
13.5, 30, 30, 12.5, 30, 30, 2.636363636, 1.588235294, 0.769230769, 
2.25, 2.416666667, 1.866666667, 6.5, 30, 14, 14, 14, 9, 3, 1.260869565, 
0.965517241, 1.588235294, 1.125, 14, 12, 30, 9.5, 13.5, 9.333333333, 
2.5, 2.5, 1.45, 1.6875, 1.666666667, 2.5, 9.333333333, 9.333333333, 
30, 12.5, 13.5, 9.333333333, 13, 3.222222222, 1.333333333, 2.444444444, 
2.5, 3.714285714, 14, 14, 30, 30, 5.5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
12, 9.5, 30, 10.5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 8, 1, 30, 30, 
10, 30, 8.5, 30, 30, 6, 30, 30, 12.5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), monthly_expense = c(2234.77, 6434, 0, 
170.2, 461.16, 1971.64, 918.45, 1280.06, 2584.93, 5676.95, 1350, 
0, 0, 6710.41, 0, 0, 692.01, 2521.26, 3481.25, 535.32, 195.45, 
22818.28, 1402.32, 0, 2232.17, 2232.17, 2683.57, 37.13, 525.54, 
2695.45, 4178.1, 1979.42, 1348.62, 5956.95, 1350, 0, 2325, 2325, 
2676.5, 166.41, 1084.69, 3594.95, 1291.39, 663.01, 610.77, 6014.49, 
2929.56, 0, 2161.25, 2161.25, 8995, 70.49, 1978.14, 2361.29, 
306.35, 994.91, 385.73, 5974.42, 2270.63, 0, 0, 239.04, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 183.46, 72.89, 0, 182.93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 523.91, 0, 
0, 239.54, 108.63, 0, 0, 192.21, 0, 30.03, 0, 0, 46.12, 0, 0, 
177.64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), time.period = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L), id = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-120L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the code:

```
library(REEMtree)
model <- REEMtree(monthly_expense ~ avg_ipt, data = sample_df, random =~1|id)
```

Does anyone know why it's throwing the error?

[image: Session Info]

Comment: I can't replicate this (it works for me on MacOS, R 3.5.0, REEMtree 0.90.3). Can you please post the results of sessionInfo() ?

Comment: I've added the session info

Comment: Can't replicate on r-devel, Ubuntu, same version of REEMtree.  It's very unlikely to be the problem, but can you try re-running with a *clean session*, i.e. no unnecessary packages loaded? (My sessionInfo() suggests that you can do it with only REEMtree + base-R packages (lattice, grid, compiler, tools, nlme, rpart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `sample_df` has the `data.frame` class, i.e. its S3 class has one element and that is `"data.frame"` -- as opposed to `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")` .

```
library(REEMtree)

sample_df <- data.frame(sample_df)
model <- REEMtree(monthly_expense ~ avg_ipt, data = sample_df, random =~1|id)
```

giving:

```
> model
[1] "*** RE-EM Tree ***"
n= 120 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 120 670354400 1166.627 *
[1] "Estimated covariance matrix of random effects:"
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)     2474326
[1] "Estimated variance of errors: 5679196.50339722"
[1] "Log likelihood:  -1098.26101212641"
```

### Note

The problem arises in REEMtree because of this line which gives a different `Target` depending on whether data is an ordinary data frame or a `tbl_df` object (and then later on in the code this difference causes the error).

```
Target <- data[, toString(TargetName)]
```

If `data` is a plain data frame then `Target` is a plain vector but if `data` is a `tbl_df` then `Target` is one too.

This would fix it:

```
Target <- data[, toString(TargetName), drop = TRUE]
```

or as `toString(TargetName)` can only be scalar:

```
Target <- data[[toString(TargetName)]]
```

Comment: @G.Grothendiek Thank you. It worked! However, I did notice the discrepancy before and I did try this before only with `as.data.frame` function. It did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: If you only have dplyr and REEMtree loaded then `class(data.frame(sample_df))` and `class(as.data.frame(sample_df))` both give `"data.frame"` but it is possible that some other packages add `as.data.frame` methods that change this.  You have quite a few packages loaded so if this acted differently for you one of those packages may have added an `as.data.frame` method of its own.